# Prove that if $\gcd (a,n)=1$, $as=1 \pmod n$ has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I can prove that if $\gcd (a,n)=1$, then $as=1 \pmod{n}$ has a solution. However, I cannot prove that the solution $s$ is in the set $\{1, 2, ..., n-1\}$.

Comment: Whatever $s$ your process comes up with, there is a unique $s'$ between $1$ and $n-1$ such that $s'\equiv s\pmod{n}$.

Comment: okay i see that. thanks!

Comment: that shold be s ≡ s' (mod n) right?

Comment: In fact this is an if and only if!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** Bezout's identity. There exists $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ such that $$ax+ny=1$$ Reduce modulo $n$.

Comment: nice hint......................+1@Foobaz

Comment: i hav edited your answer